# How do I test how a mobile app gets foregrounded?

Tags: react-native, testing, automated-tests

I've got a `create-react-native-app` and I need to write a test to prevent a regression of an issue when users bring the app back to the foreground (it seems to have difficulty reconnecting the socket.io connection).

Currently I have to manually test this by following some steps:

1. Open the app
2. Log in
3. Wait for login to complete
4. Switch to another app (background it)
5. Wait for backgrounded app to lose its server connection (~20 seconds)
6. Re-open app (foreground it)
7. Check if issue occurs

How do I go about writing automated tests for this? I'm using `jest` for unit testing within the app.

Comment: Also trying to figure this out. Did you ever end up finding a solution?

Comment: Nope, still doing it manually unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

> Basic Usage

To see the current state, you can check AppState.currentState, which will be kept up-to-date. However, currentState will be null at launch while AppState retrieves it over the bridge.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native'

class AppStateExample extends Component {

  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I'm explaining the problem well enough. I know in the app how to check for state changes, I just don't know how to put that through a test suite.  When the app is foregrounded, the socket is in some weird state where it thinks it is connected but isn't actually (I guess because it was saved as connected when it backrounded). So I need to test that the app successfully reconnects on foregrounding